# Uploading "Profile Image" on Profile Page

Tags: php, mysql, database, security

I found some code online to access my database to retrieve the stored file with the mime extension and read that information to the directory where I stored the actual image. [Link to the code source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-upload-image-into-database-and-display-it-using-php/)

```php
<div id="display-image">
    <?php
    
    $query = " select * from image ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
 
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
        <img src="./image/<?php echo $data['filename']; ?> "> 
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I like to use `die` or `exit(0)` whenever I access my `database`. However, the page fails to load correctly when I use it with this code.

Here's the way I coded it:

```
<?php
// This page uploads the profile pic into the profile page
include("database_connection.php");

$user = $_SESSION['active_user']['username'];
$get_img = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE User='$user' LIMIT 1";

$runit = mysqli_query($db,$get_img);
while($pic = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runit)) { ?>
    <img src="img/<?php echo $pic['image_file01']; ?>" ><?php
    exit(0); 
}
?>
```

So the above code is in a separate file that I include on my profile page like this:

```php
<div class="body-align-left">
    <br><br>
    <!-- Profile Image-->
    <?php include('upload.php'); ?>
</div>
```

Although the code seemingly works fine, I am not sure that using the while statement is a golden way to go about this. Additionally, I would like to know how secure this code is. What would be a better approach? As I said, if I try to use `exit(0)` or `die` within the code block doesn't load the page entirely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SQL Injection Vulnerability

Your current approach exposes your application to **serious** [**SQL injections**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). You're currently inserting the `username` directly from the `session` into the `SQL` query, which can be leveraged to `execute` arbitrary `SQL` statements.

**Solution**: Always use `prepared` statements to mitigate this risk.

```php
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT image_file01 FROM test WHERE User=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
```

In the example above, the `?` character serves as a placeholder for `User`, and we `bind` the actual value (from `$user`) using `bind_param`. This ensures the value is treated as a `string`, preventing potential `SQL` injections.

---

### Improving Loop Structure

Since you've set `... LIMIT 1` in your `SQL` query, you expect at most one result. Thus, using `exit` within the loop is unnecessary. Moreover, since you're only fetching one result, an `if` check is more appropriate than a `while` loop.

**Improvement**: Here's an example of how you could use `if` statements to streamline your logic:

```php
// First execute the prepared query
if ($stmt->execute()) {

    // Get the results:
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // If a profile image is found, echo the image
    if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<img src="img/' . $row['image_file01'] . '" >';
    } 
    
    // No images were found. Here, you do whatever you want.
    // For example, display a default profile image.
    // If you want nothing to happen, you can remove this 
    // else statement completely.
    else {
        echo "No image found.";
    }
} 

// Prepared query failed
else {
    echo "Database error: " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Comment: Awesome information! This is exactly what I was hoping to learn! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome and welcome to Stack Overflow! I highly recommend reading more about SQL injections since they can lead to severe issues. I added a link to the previous answer. The article is very beginner-friendly and easy to understand.

Comment: I'm about to check your link out now. I do appreciate your information! I thought the only way to run a query was via mysqli_query() function. I really like the prepared statements better so I'm recoding my entire register/login based upon these prepared statements. Just extra info, I do use preg_replace() function for all incoming queries. I replace all the sketchy chars then store that into a variable and transfer that into my database. To your knowledge are there any major security risk for doing this?